# Puzzle - connecting nodes

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

This might not be the right stack exchange, so if there's a better place to put it please let me know.

I have the following problem. Given the following graph, ignoring X, find all possible connections without lines crossing. Then for each graph say where X must be placed. (lines must be inside the outer box and outside the three 'islands')

[image: Problem]

The solution I have come up with is below. The way I see it the B-B line must be done first keeping A and X on one side and C,D,E on the other. I think the one below is only one that does this. Therefore I get the solution and combinations of how A wraps around the island and how the group C,D,E wrap around the other islands. Therefore the other X must be on the outside left between the two Bs or on the same island as the original X. Is this correct? Something doesn't feel right to me that all solutions have the same answer for X.

[image: My Solution]

Comment: Incidentally, have to played the game *Flow Free?* It consists of variations of this puzzle on a grid.  http://html5games.com/2012/07/flow-free/